# encode and decode text to reduce application file size

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, encoding, pseudocode

I am developing a dictionary. Where there is huge file of more than 2.5 million words and it's translation. Let's consider this Google translator http://translate.google.com/#auto/ar/people Where you can see below noun, verb. In those noun and verb you will find some repeating words.

So what I am trying to say if there is any encode or decode seudo code for representing those repeating text to some kind of symbols so the file size will be reduced? As for sure there will be repeating of same word so many times in the database.

Comment: That would be something like a Huffword coder, i.e. a Huffman coding scheme with a fixed dictionary.

Comment: In the link provided, they are not repeating words, they are synonyms.  Each one is unique.

2.5 million words are considerably small size not a huge file size, if you use coredata.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Because it's an app. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/arabic-to-english-dictionary/id408908533?mt=8 I have now 1,17,000 words and it's now 17MB. But if I have 2.5 million it will be huge. Because those synonyms will be of course repeated in the app so many times.

Comment: @VolkerK Thank you for your email. Can you give me a link or explain bit more about Huffword coding? Thank you

Comment: @Ekram: Your one word is taking more than 150 bytes. How you are storing them?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya actually that 17MB is total app size not the DB size. I am storing it as XML file. I am trying to find a solution to represent small size by which some repeating synonyms in noun,verb section can be stored in less size. Cause those 2.5 million words will have so much same synonyms which will make the DB file huge size. And most likely user wont download the app for iPhone/iPad using mobile 3G internet. It's always recommended to keep below 10MB size of the full app to let user download it without hesitation. Hope you understand the problem.

Comment: thats why I said go with **coredata/sqlite**

Comment: @AnoopVaidya yes but even that sqlite will store those text in the db. Let's say I have a word called "pronunciation" If I can store it like only 2-3 character like "?#%" then I can save at least 10 characters from this one word. Just now think how much bytes I can save for just encoding the similar text/words. You got my point?